# Errors (Type Error and You cannot render a <Router>...) in React app using Router

Tags: reactjs

I want to use a Link tag to navigation another section in my single-page app.

But I got an error that You cannot render a  inside another . You should never have more than one in your app.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link, BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import styles from "./Navbar.module.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";

import Hero from "./Hero";
import About from "../AboutSection/About";

const Navbar = () => {
  useEffect(() => {}, []);

  return (
    <Router basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
      <header id="header" className="fixed-top">
        <div className="container d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
          <h1 className={styles.logo}>
            <Link to="/">Logo</Link>
          </h1>
          <nav id="navbar" className="navbar" style={{ padding: "0" }}>
            <ul className={styles.navbar_ul}>
              <li className={styles.navbar_li}>
                <Link to="/" className=" nav-link scrollto">
                  Home
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li className={styles.navbar_li}>
                <Link to="/about" className="nav-link scrollto">
                  About
                </Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <i className="bi bi-list mobile-nav-toggle"></i>
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<Hero />} />
              <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
            </Routes>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </header>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

so I deleted the   and changed to import { Link, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
and now it shows
Cannot destructure property 'basename' of 'react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.useContext(...)' as it is null.
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'basename' of 'react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.useContext(...)' as it is null.

What is the problem and how can I fix my code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using React Dev tools, take a look at the value of the basename props in the Router.  It's null.

These errors are about how env variables 'get resolved' during build time. process.env is not available on the client side as its a node api and webpack configurations resolve that with various mechanisms during the build.

**But**, that doesn't really matter in this circumstance. The basename starts at the root of your app, it doesn't want a web url.  Router basename="/" is the starting route regardless of hosted site. If you want to restrict the router to a subsection basename="/aboutsection" you can do that.

Also React-Router really suggests you use the high level routers and not to directly use Router.

https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/router

https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/react-router-quick/9781789532555/6d011473-28c0-415b-99bc-12b2df13b116.xhtml